# SUMPRODUCT on ranges with numbers and chars

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following with the correct result.

[image]

The issue is when I have characters in the D4:G7 range. The result is #VALUE!

[image]

So the question is how can I sum the values from that range excepting the characters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one has the new Dynamic Array Formula Filter then using SUM, which ignores text:

```
=SUM(FILTER(D4:G7,(B4:B7=C10)*(C4:C7=C11)))
```

[image]

---

If one does not then one must use an array version of SUM:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(D4:G7),D4:G7)*(B4:B7=C10)*(C4:C7=C11))
```

Being an array one needs to confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: doesn't seem to behave correctly if I update any of the filters like Cat1 -> Cat2  in C11. I get !CALC! At least the first option with FILTER

Comment: Then there are none that satisfy both condition.  There are no rows that satisfy both `t1` AND `Cat2`

Comment: Working well! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @sboketweb please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: as a bonus....:D ..what if i need to sum the numbers + all the counts where I have let's say "w" (every appearance of a specific character to be considered 1 in the sum.

Comment: Change the IF to `IF(ISNUMBER(D4:G7),D4:G7,IF(D4:G7="w",1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can supplement the original formula with `IFERROR` function to exclude text:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B4:B7=C10)*(C4:C7=C11)*IFERROR(D4:G7;0))
```